# Numpy: create a "superset" array view

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a view `x_` of a vector `x` that is augmented, but still references the same memory location as `x`. That way, I don't need to run an augment function every time I want the augmented vector, but can simply refer to `x_`.

Is there a way to re-write this so that the assertion below is true? I am looking to maximize efficiency.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
ones = np.ones(len(x), dtype=x.dtype)

x_ = np.stack([x, ones], axis=0)
x[0] = 11

assert x_[0, 0] == 11
```

Note: I have a feeling that this could be impossible or inefficient because it would break contiguous storage. I would appreciate an explanation if this is the case.

Comment: `x_` is a whole new array, with values copied from `x`, but no memory or reference connection.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to create `x_` such that it has a memory reference to `x`?